# Oracle Hierarchical Query Returning Duplicate Instead of Transitive Parent/Child Pair

Tags: sql, oracle, hierarchical-data

I'm trying to make what I think is a fairly basic hierarchical query, but the results aren't what I'm expecting.

I have a table of merged companies and want to get the transitive ID's if a merged company has then been merged into another company.

Starting with this base data:

| company_id | merged_company_id |
| --- | --- |
| 21 | 10 |
| 21 | 22 |
| 22 | 45 |

Where company 10 has been merged into company 21.

I want to generate a query that finds any transitive mergers as well. Showing that company 45 is now also considered merged into company 21, since it's parent company has been merged into 21.

| company_id | merged_company_id |
| --- | --- |
| 21 | 10 |
| 21 | 22 |
| 21 | 45 |
| 22 | 45 |

I've been playing around with connect by queries, but getting unexpected results.

```sql
with base as (
    select
        company_id,
        merged_company_id
    from
        merged_companies
    where 
        merged_companies.company_id in ('21','22')
)
select
    *
from
    base
connect by
    prior base.company_id = base.merged_company_id
order by
    base.company_id, base.merged_company_id
```

I can't figure out why it's giving me these results. Instead of the 21/45 pairing I'm looking for, I get a duplicate 22/45.

| company_id | merged_company_id |
| --- | --- |
| 21 | 10 |
| 21 | 22 |
| 22 | 45 |
| 22 | 45 |

I feel like I have a fundamental misunderstanding of these hierarchical queries. I'm assuming I don't need a `start with` here, since I want to get the hierarchy for all records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `CONNECT_BY_ROOT` to get the root `company_id` (rather than the `company_id` from the current level of the query):

```sql
SELECT CONNECT_BY_ROOT company_id AS company_id,
       merged_company_id
FROM   table_name
CONNECT BY PRIOR merged_company_id = company_id
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (company_id, merged_company_id) AS
SELECT 21, 10 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 21, 22 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 22, 45 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| COMPANY_ID | MERGED_COMPANY_ID |
| --- | --- |
| 21 | 10 |
| 21 | 22 |
| 21 | 45 |
| 22 | 45 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/k0Rbica5)